# Being annoyed at Nasheed?

Tags: shirk

Asalamualaikum my question is: I was in the livingroom together with my family and my sister was doing her homework while  singing a nasheed very loud and I got really annoyed and made an annoyed sound is this shirk?

Comment: What does this situation have anything to do with shirk...?

Answer (score 0):

Its not shirk, nasheeds aren't even from the Quran and Sunnah (not say nasheeds are bad). It's normal to be annoyed at something if it's played or said loudly.